# Ansible notify handler doen't execute

Tags: ansible

Ok, It is my task:

```
---
- name: copy source list
  copy: src=sources.list dest=/etc/apt/sources.list
  notify: update apt

# - name: Update apt
#   shell: apt-get update

- name: Install postgres
  shell: apt-get install -q -y postgresql-9.1
  #apt: name=postgresql-9.1  state=present 

- others tasks...
```

Here is my handler:

```
- name: update apt
  action: apt-get update
```

When I run it doesn't notify.

```
...

TASK: [postgresql | copy source list] ***************************************** 
changed: [host_slave2]
changed: [host_slave1]
changed: [host_pgpool]
changed: [host_master]

TASK: [postgresql | Install postgres] ***************************************** 
changed: [host_slave1]
changed: [host_master]
changed: [host_slave2]
changed: [host_pgpool]

...
```

After the copy I should have to see the notification, what is wrong?

Comment: notify comes at the very end of the run- did you cancel or let it run to the end? I'd suggest increasing verbosity too. Finally, [the apt* modules](http://docs.ansible.com/list_of_packaging_modules.html) are great.

Answer (score 1):

```
---

- name: copy source list
  copy: src=sources.list dest=/etc/apt/sources.list
#http://docs.ansible.com/apt_repository_module.html
  register: update_apt

- name: Update apt
  apt: update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=86400
#http://docs.ansible.com/apt_module.html
  when: update_apt is defined and update_apt.changed == True

- name: Install postgres
  shell: apt-get install -q -y postgresql-9.1
  #apt: name=postgresql-9.1  state=present 

- others tasks...
```

Comment: While the suggested answer will work, it's not using ansible handlers as per the original question.

Answer (score 0):

http://wherenow.org/ansible-handlers/

In fact the issue is necessary to force the implementation of

```
---
- name: copy source list
  copy: src=sources.list dest=/etc/apt/sources.list
  notify: update apt

- meta: flush_handlers


- name: Install postgres
  shell: apt-get install -q -y postgresql-9.1
  #apt: name=postgresql-9.1  state=present 

- others tasks... 

handler:

- name: update apt
  action: apt-get update
```